# Opengl texture function sometimes breaks shader

Tags: opengl, rust, glsl, shader

I am working on implementing point lighting in a small maze application with OpenGl and Rust. I had everything working, until I wanted shadows. I generate an empty cubemap and attach it to a framebuffer attempting to follow this tutorial [Learn Opengl Point Shadow tutorail](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/5.advanced_lighting/3.2.2.point_shadows_soft/point_shadows_soft.cpp)(The code is at the bottom [here](https://learnopengl.com/code_viewer_gh.php?code=src/5.advanced_lighting/3.2.2.point_shadows_soft/point_shadows_soft.cpp))

The main fragment shader code that seems to be the issue is this

```c
#version 330 core
out vec4 FragColor;

struct Material {
    sampler2D diffuse;
    sampler2D specular;
    float shininess;
};

struct PointLight {
    vec3 position;

    float constant;
    float linear;
    float quadratic;

    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

in vec3 FragPos;
in vec3 Normal;
in vec2 TexCords;
in vec4 ourColor;

uniform vec3 viewPos;
uniform PointLight pointLight;
uniform Material material;
uniform float far_plane;
uniform samplerCube depthMap;


vec3 gridSamplingDisk[20] = vec3[](
   vec3(1, 1,  1), vec3( 1, -1,  1), vec3(-1, -1,  1), vec3(-1, 1,  1),
   vec3(1, 1, -1), vec3( 1, -1, -1), vec3(-1, -1, -1), vec3(-1, 1, -1),
   vec3(1, 1,  0), vec3( 1, -1,  0), vec3(-1, -1,  0), vec3(-1, 1,  0),
   vec3(1, 0,  1), vec3(-1,  0,  1), vec3( 1,  0, -1), vec3(-1, 0, -1),
   vec3(0, 1,  1), vec3( 0, -1,  1), vec3( 0, -1, -1), vec3( 0, 1, -1)
);

vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir);
float ShadowCalculations(vec3 fragPos);

void main()
{
    // properties
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - FragPos);

    FragColor = vec4(CalcPointLight(pointLight, norm, FragPos, viewDir), 1.0);

}


// calculates the color when using a point light.
vec3 CalcPointLight(PointLight light, vec3 normal, vec3 fragPos, vec3 viewDir)
{
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.position - fragPos);
    // diffuse shading
    float diff = max(dot(normal, lightDir), 0.0);
    // specular shading
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir, normal);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0), material.shininess);
    // attenuation
    float distance = length(light.position - fragPos);
    float attenuation = 1.0 / (light.constant + light.linear * distance + light.quadratic * (distance * distance));
    // combine results
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCords));
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse * diff * vec3(texture(material.diffuse, TexCords));
    vec3 specular = light.specular * spec * vec3(texture(material.specular, TexCords));
    ambient *= attenuation;
    diffuse *= attenuation;
    specular *= attenuation;


    float shadow = 0.0;
    // float shadow = ShadowCalculations(fragPos);
    return (ambient + (1.0 - shadow) * (diffuse + specular)) ;
}

float ShadowCalculations(vec3 fragPos){
    // get vector between fragment position and light position
    vec3 fragToLight = fragPos - pointLight.position;
    // use the fragment to light vector to sample from the depth map
    // float closestDepth = texture(depthMap, fragToLight).r;
    // it is currently in linear range between [0,1], let's re-transform it back to original depth value
    // closestDepth *= far_plane;
    // now get current linear depth as the length between the fragment and light position




    float currentDepth = length(fragToLight);




    // test for shadows
    // float bias = 0.05; // we use a much larger bias since depth is now in [near_plane, far_plane] range
    // float shadow = currentDepth -  bias > closestDepth ? 1.0 : 0.0;
    // PCF
    // float shadow = 0.0;
    // float bias = 0.05;
    // float samples = 4.0;
    // float offset = 0.1;
    // for(float x = -offset; x < offset; x += offset / (samples * 0.5))
    // {
        // for(float y = -offset; y < offset; y += offset / (samples * 0.5))
        // {
            // for(float z = -offset; z < offset; z += offset / (samples * 0.5))
            // {
                // float closestDepth = texture(depthMap, fragToLight + vec3(x, y, z)).r; // use lightdir to lookup cubemap
                // closestDepth *= far_plane;   // Undo mapping [0;1]
                // if(currentDepth - bias > closestDepth)
                    // shadow += 1.0;
            // }
        // }
    // }
    // shadow /= (samples * samples * samples);





    float shadow = 0.0;
    float bias = 0.15;
    int samples = 20;
    float viewDistance = length(viewPos - fragPos);
    float diskRadius = (1.0 + (viewDistance / far_plane)) / 25.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < samples; ++i)
    {
        // this is the bad line of code
        float closestDepth = texture(depthMap, fragToLight + gridSamplingDisk[i] * diskRadius).r;
        closestDepth *= far_plane;   // undo mapping [0;1]
        if(currentDepth - bias > closestDepth) {
            shadow += 1.0;
        }
    }
    shadow /= float(samples);

    // display closestDepth as debug (to visualize depth cubemap)
    // FragColor = vec4(vec3(closestDepth / far_plane), 1.0);

    return shadow;
}
// calculates the color when using a spot light.
```

But for some reason when I run the texture function on the depth map the fragment shader just stops running but if I don't run the pointLight the shadow function "works" (at least renders something to the screen I don't know about its accuracy but I'll deal with that later)

For example

```c
void main() {
   float r = texture(depthMap, vec3(1.0)).r; 
   FragColor = vec4(r,1.0);
}
```

This works but if I run it inside the CalculatePointLight routine opengl doesn't render anything. There seems to be some problem with both of these running since either one of them alone won't break the shader, but if both of them are in the same program it won't work correctly

the main rust program is

```rust
use std::{fs::read_to_string, path::Path};

use cgmath::{perspective, vec3, vec4, Deg, EuclideanSpace, Matrix4, Point3};
use glfw::{Action, Key};
use learn_opengl::{
    camera::{Camera, CameraDirection, CameraDirectionTrait},
    gls::{
        buffers::{
            bindable::Bindable,
            framebuffer::FrameBuffer,
            texture::{CubeMap, Texture2D},
            Attribute, VOs,
        },
        shader::{Shader, ShaderProgram},
    },
    lights::{material::Material, point_lights::PointLightBuilder},
    window::Window,
};

use maze::logic::{Maze, MazeEntry, MazeIndex};
const SCR_WIDTH: u32 = 1600;
const SCR_HEIGHT: u32 = 1200;

const VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE: &'static str = include_str!("../../shader/vert.glsl");
const FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE: &'static str = include_str!("../../shader/frag.glsl");

const VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE_LAMP: &'static str = include_str!("../../shader/lamp_vert.glsl");
const FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE_LAMP: &'static str = include_str!("../../shader/lamp_frag.glsl");

const VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE_DEPTH: &'static str = include_str!("../../shader/depth_vs.glsl");
const FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE_DEPTH: &'static str = include_str!("../../shader/depth_fs.glsl");
const GEOMETRY_SHADER_SOURCE_DEPTH: &'static str = include_str!("../../shader/depth_ge.glsl");

fn main() {
    let mut maze: Maze = read_to_string("./maze.txt")
        .expect("Failed to find file maze.txt")
        .parse()
        .expect("Error parsing maze");
    let mut window = Window::new(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "Learn Opengl", false, false).unwrap();
    let shader = ShaderProgram::new([
        Shader::new(VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE, gl::VERTEX_SHADER).expect("Failed to Compile V Shader"),
        Shader::new(FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE, gl::FRAGMENT_SHADER)
            .expect("Failed to Compile F Normal Shader"),
    ])
    .expect("Failed to Create Shader Program");
    let lamp_shader = ShaderProgram::new([
        Shader::new(VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE_LAMP, gl::VERTEX_SHADER)
            .expect("Failed to Compile V Shader"),
        Shader::new(FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE_LAMP, gl::FRAGMENT_SHADER)
            .expect("Failed to Compile F Lamp Shader"),
    ])
    .expect("Failed to Create Shader Program");

    let depth_shader = ShaderProgram::new([
        Shader::new(VERTEX_SHADER_SOURCE_DEPTH, gl::VERTEX_SHADER)
            .expect("Failed to Compile V Shader"),
        Shader::new(FRAGMENT_SHADER_SOURCE_DEPTH, gl::FRAGMENT_SHADER)
            .expect("Failed to Compile F Depth Shader"),
        Shader::new(GEOMETRY_SHADER_SOURCE_DEPTH, gl::GEOMETRY_SHADER)
            .expect("Failed to Compile G Shader"),
    ])
    .expect("Failed to Create Shader Program Depth");

    #[rustfmt::skip]
    let cube_verts: [f32; 288] = [
        // positions       // normals        // texture coords
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
         0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0,
         0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,

        -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,
         0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  0.0,
         0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,
        -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,

        -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
        -0.5,  0.5, -0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
        -0.5, -0.5,  0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
        -0.5,  0.5,  0.5, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,

         0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
         0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
         0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
         0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
         0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,

        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
         0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
         0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
        -0.5, -0.5,  0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
        -0.5, -0.5, -0.5,  0.0, -1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,

        -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0,
         0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  1.0,
         0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
         0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,
        -0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
        -0.5,  0.5, -0.5,  0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  1.0
        ];
    let attributes = [
        Attribute {
            // cords
            location: 0,
            size: 3,
            normalized: false,
            stride: 8,
            offset: 0,
        },
        Attribute {
            // normal
            location: 1,
            size: 3,
            normalized: false,
            stride: 8,
            offset: 3,
        },
        Attribute {
            // texture
            location: 2,
            size: 2,
            normalized: false,
            stride: 8,
            offset: 6,
        },
    ];
    let vbo_vba =
        VOs::new(&cube_verts, &attributes, gl::TRIANGLES).expect("vbo or vba failed to bind");

    // textures
    let floor_textures = [
        Texture2D::new(
            image::open(&Path::new("./maze/resources/floor/albedo.jpg")).unwrap(),
            [gl::REPEAT, gl::REPEAT],
            [gl::LINEAR, gl::LINEAR],
            gl::RGB,
            None,
        )
        .unwrap(),
        Texture2D::new(
            image::open(&Path::new("./maze/resources/floor/specular.jpg")).unwrap(),
            [gl::REPEAT, gl::REPEAT],
            [gl::LINEAR, gl::LINEAR],
            gl::RGB,
            None,
        )
        .unwrap(),
    ];

    let floor_texture =
        learn_opengl::gls::buffers::texture::Textures::<2>::new(core::array::from_fn(|i| {
            &floor_textures[i]
        }))
        .unwrap();
    floor_texture.bind().unwrap();

    const SHADOW_WIDTH: i32 = 1024;
    const SHADOW_HEIGHT: i32 = 1024;

    let depth_map_fbo = FrameBuffer::new();

    let cube_map = CubeMap::new(SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT, gl::DEPTH_COMPONENT)
        .expect("Couldn't make cube map");

    depth_map_fbo
        .attach_tex(&cube_map, gl::DEPTH_ATTACHMENT)
        .expect("failled attaching cubemap to depth buffer");

    depth_map_fbo.drr().unwrap();
    depth_map_fbo.unbind().unwrap();

    shader
        .set_uniform("material", Material::new(0, 1, 0.5))
        .expect("error with material");

    shader.set_uniform("depthMap", 1).unwrap();

    let point_light = PointLightBuilder::default()
        .pos(maze.get_player_loc() + vec3(0., 0., 0.))
        .build();

    shader
        .set_uniform("pointLight", &point_light)
        .expect("couldn't send point light uniform");

    let mut cam = Camera::new(
        Point3::from_vec(maze.get_player_loc()),
        90f32,
        0f32,
        vec3(2.5, 2.5, 2.5),
    );
    shader.set_uniform("viewPos", cam.get_pos()).unwrap();

    let mut projection: Matrix4<f32> =
        perspective(Deg(45.0), SCR_WIDTH as f32 / SCR_HEIGHT as f32, 0.1, 100.0);

    shader.set_uniform("projection", projection).unwrap();
    lamp_shader.set_uniform("projection", projection).unwrap();

    let near_plane = 1.0f32;
    let far_plane = 25.0f32;
    shader.set_uniform("far_plane", far_plane).unwrap();

    let shadow_proj = perspective(
        Deg(90.),
        SHADOW_WIDTH as f32 / SHADOW_HEIGHT as f32,
        near_plane,
        far_plane,
    );

    let shadow_transforms = vec![
        shadow_proj
            * Matrix4::look_at_rh(
                Point3::from_vec(point_light.get_pos()),
                Point3::from_vec(point_light.get_pos() + vec3(1., 0., 0.)),
                vec3(0., -1., 0.),
            ),
        shadow_proj
            * Matrix4::look_at_rh(
                Point3::from_vec(point_light.get_pos()),
                Point3::from_vec(point_light.get_pos() + vec3(-1., 0., 0.)),
                vec3(0., -1., 0.),
            ),
        shadow_proj
            * Matrix4::look_at_rh(
                Point3::from_vec(point_light.get_pos()),
                Point3::from_vec(point_light.get_pos() + vec3(0., 1., 0.)),
                vec3(0., 0., 1.),
            ),
        shadow_proj
            * Matrix4::look_at_rh(
                Point3::from_vec(point_light.get_pos()),
                Point3::from_vec(point_light.get_pos() + vec3(0., -1., 0.)),
                vec3(0., 0., -1.),
            ),
        shadow_proj
            * Matrix4::look_at_rh(
                Point3::from_vec(point_light.get_pos()),
                Point3::from_vec(point_light.get_pos() + vec3(0., 0., 1.)),
                vec3(0., -1., 0.),
            ),
        shadow_proj
            * Matrix4::look_at_rh(
                Point3::from_vec(point_light.get_pos()),
                Point3::from_vec(point_light.get_pos() + vec3(0., 0., -1.)),
                vec3(0., -1., 0.),
            ),
    ];
    depth_shader
        .set_uniform("shadowMatricies", shadow_transforms)
        .unwrap();
    depth_shader.set_uniform("far_plane", far_plane).unwrap();
    depth_shader
        .set_uniform("lightPos", point_light.get_pos())
        .unwrap();

    window.app_loop(|mut w| {
        // Pre Stuff
        process_events(&mut w, &mut cam, &mut projection);
        let dir = process_input(&mut w.window);
        if let Some(dir) = dir {
            if dir != 0 {
                let time = w.delta_time;
                let new_pos: MazeIndex = cam.try_translate_camera(dir, time).into();
                if maze[new_pos] != MazeEntry::Wall {
                    cam.translate_camera(dir, time);
                    shader.set_uniform("viewPos", cam.get_pos()).unwrap();
                    maze.move_player_to(new_pos);
                }
            }
        }
        let view = cam.get_view();
        // 1. render scene to depth cubemap
        //
        unsafe {
            gl::Viewport(0, 0, SHADOW_WIDTH, SHADOW_HEIGHT);
            depth_map_fbo.bind().unwrap();
            gl::Clear(gl::DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        }

        depth_shader.use_program();
        render(&vbo_vba, &depth_shader, &maze);
        depth_map_fbo.unbind().unwrap();
        //
        // // 2. render normally
        unsafe {
            gl::Viewport(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH as i32, SCR_HEIGHT as i32);
            gl::Clear(gl::DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | gl::COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        }
        shader.set_uniform("view", view.clone()).unwrap();
        cube_map.bind().unwrap();
        render(&vbo_vba, &shader, &maze);

        lamp_shader.use_program();
        lamp_shader.set_uniform("view", view).unwrap();
        lamp_shader
            .set_uniform(
                "model",
                Matrix4::from_translation(point_light.get_pos()) * Matrix4::from_scale(0.2),
            )
            .unwrap();
        vbo_vba.draw_arrays(0, 36).unwrap();
    });
}

fn render(vbo_vba: &VOs, shader: &ShaderProgram, maze: &Maze) {
    for (y, row) in maze.iter().enumerate() {
        for (x, entry) in row.iter().enumerate() {
            let model: Matrix4<f32> = match entry {
                maze::logic::MazeEntry::Wall => {
                    Matrix4::from_translation(vec3(x as f32, 1., y as f32))
                }
                _ => Matrix4::from_translation(vec3(x as f32, 0., y as f32)),
            };
            shader.set_uniform("model", model).unwrap();
            vbo_vba.draw_arrays(0, 36).unwrap();
        }
    }
}

fn process_events(w: &mut Window, cam: &mut Camera, proj: &mut Matrix4<f32>) -> bool {
    for (_, event) in glfw::flush_messages(&w.events) {
        match event {
            glfw::WindowEvent::FramebufferSize(width, height) => {
                // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and
                // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
                w.width = width as u32;
                w.height = height as u32;
                *proj = perspective(Deg(45.0), SCR_WIDTH as f32 / SCR_HEIGHT as f32, 0.1, 100.0);
                unsafe {
                    gl::Viewport(0, 0, width, height);
                };
            }
            glfw::WindowEvent::CursorPos(x, y) => {
                cam.move_point_pos(x as f32, y as f32);
            }
            _ => {}
        };
    }
    return false;
}
fn process_input(window: &mut glfw::Window) -> Option<CameraDirection> {
    if window.get_key(Key::Escape) == Action::Press {
        window.set_should_close(true);
        return None;
    }
    let mut dirs = CameraDirection::new();

    if window.get_key(Key::W) == Action::Press {
        dirs.toggle_forward();
    }

    if window.get_key(Key::S) == Action::Press {
        dirs.toggle_backward();
    }

    if window.get_key(Key::D) == Action::Press {
        dirs.toggle_right();
    }

    if window.get_key(Key::A) == Action::Press {
        dirs.toggle_left();
    }

    // if window.get_key(Key::LeftShift) == Action::Press {
    //     dirs.toggle_down();
    // }
    //
    // if window.get_key(Key::Space) == Action::Press {
    //     dirs.toggle_up();
    // }
    return Some(dirs);
}
```

here, there are a couple of attached files that are important Ill just link the [repo](https://github.com/GIP2000/Computer-Graphics/tree/project/maze/maze) in case they are relevant (ignore the mediocre api design this was my first time playing with opengl)

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. I never activated the cubemap texture. (still doesn't work but apparently trying to use a sampler2D instead of a cubemap will cause opengl to silently fail)